# Angular app not working on Safari after update to v15

Tags: angular, safari, mobile-safari, angular15, browser-support

Few weeks ago I had update our app from Angular 14 to v15.1.6 and since then we get an error on Safari < v16 due to ReferenceError

I found that it was a known bug solved last dezember.
The experience seem to be exactly the same:
Web app not loading /
ReferenceError on the console /
Reloading with DevTools opened brings a correct loading.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24355

Checking our code base it looks that we do have the fix for that bug, but we are still getting the issue.

Our browserlist is the following:

```
> 5%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, not dead, not IE 9, not IE 10, not IE 11, not Chrome 41
```

and we our browserslist-stats.json states the following for Safari, though I have not much knowledge on this:

```
"ios_saf": {
    "8": 0,
    "3.2": 0.0002755352271787948,
    "4.0-4.1": 0,
    "4.2-4.3": 0,
    "5.0-5.1": 0.0022042818174303584,
    "6.0-6.1": 0.0002755352271787948,
    "7.0-7.1": 0.0016532113630727688,
    "8.1-8.4": 0.0019287465902515636,
    "9.0-9.2": 0.008817127269721434,
    "9.3": 0.11627586586945142,
    "10.0-10.2": 0.307497313531535,
    "10.3": 1.5807455983247458,
    "11.0-11.2": 3.4590692420025904,
    "11.3-11.4": 6.929986498773869,
    "12.0-12.1": 12.084423993607583,
    "12.2": 2.2161298321990466
  },
...
"safari": {
    "4": 0.0008266056815363844,
    "5": 0,
    "6": 0,
    "7": 0,
    "8": 0.0011021409087151792,
    "9": 0.00633731022511228,
    "10": 0.0022042818174303584,
    "11": 0.13391012040889427,
    "12": 0.18488413743697132,
    "3.1": 0,
    "3.2": 0,
    "5.1": 0,
    "6.1": 0.0005510704543575896,
    "7.1": 0,
    "9.1": 0.00743945113382746,
    "10.1": 0.022593888628661175,
    "11.1": 0.15540186812884027,
    "12.1": 0.03278869203427658,
    "TP": 0
  },
```

Any idea what it may be wrong?

This is angular version details:

```
Angular CLI: 15.1.6
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.19
OS: linux x64

Angular: 15.1.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1501.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.1.6
@angular-devkit/core            15.1.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.1.6
@angular/cdk                    15.2.0
@angular/cli                    15.1.6
@angular/flex-layout            15.0.0-beta.42
@angular/google-maps            14.2.0
@angular/material               15.2.0
@nguniversal/builders           15.1.0
@nguniversal/common             15.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine     15.1.0
@schematics/angular             14.2.1
@schematics/update              0.1102.18
rxjs                            7.5.6
typescript                      4.9.5
webpack                         5.76.0
```